# Evaluating Swift's Bool? for true/false/nil in one line?

Tags: swift, option-type

I've got a lot of code like this:

```
if let x = optbool {
   return f(x)
} else {
   return false
}
```

Can this be expressed on a single line?

Comment: Consider to redesign the code to get rid of the optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statement is equivalent to your code:

```
return optbool.map(f) ?? false
```

If `optbool == nil` then `.map(f)` returns `nil`,
and the nil-coalescing operator `?? false` changes that
to  `false`.

If `optbool != nil` then `.map(f)` returns `f(optbool!)`,
which is also the result of the nil-coalescing operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return optbool != nil ? f(optbool!) : false
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is valid only if func f(x:Bool)->Bool

```
func foo(b: Bool?)-> Bool {
    if let x = b {
        return f(x)
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

now the question has no logic more ... and you can use one of this

```
let res1 = f(b ?? false)
let res2 = f(b ?? true)
let res3 = !f(b ?? false)
let res4 = !f(b ?? true)
```

depending on your f function

Answer (score 0):

If you define the `f` function as an extension of `Bool`:

```
extension Bool {
    func f() -> Bool {
        return true // or false..
    }
}
```

then you can write

```
return x?.f() ?? false
```

or

```
return x?.f() == true
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is really:

> Can this be expressed on a single line?

The answer is undoubtedly YES:

```
if let x = optbool { return f(x) } else { return false }
```

;-)

Seriously, if `optbool` is not supposed to be `nil`, I would rather write it on 2 lines:

```
guard let x = optbool else { return false }
return f(x)
```